# Modal verbs for logical deduction

Tags: modal-verbs

What's the difference between *must* and *should* when  used for logical deduction? Can they be used interchangeably? Here's an example:

"You must be tired after your long journey."      - MUST

"I've revised so I should be ready for the test." - SHOULD

Is it correct to write "You SHOULD be tired after your long journey"  ?

Is it correct to write "I've revised so I MUST be ready for the test" ?

Comment: No, they're not interchangeable. You _can_ write all four of those sentences, but the pairs have slightly different meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While both *must* and *should* are "square" [modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) -- the ones that mean logical `Necessary`,
which is represented by   `⃤` in formulae -- their usage in English shows differences.

As deontic modals, *must* means 'obligatory', while *should* means 'strongly advised'.

- *You must include your phone number; otherwise it's incomplete.*
- *You should include your phone number; we may need to contact you.*

But as epistemic modals, *should* is not just a weak *must* -- it appears to refer to the variety of cognition involved in drawing the conclusion.

- *I see a lot of cars in the parking lot; they must be open.*
- *It's after 9:30; they should be open.*

In the first example above, *must* is used to express a conclusion from evidence or experience;
while in the second, *should* is used to express a conclusion from theory or expectation.
You could  say epistemic *should* is a priori and epistemic *must* is a posteriori.

Comment: Also, 'should' has (at least) two distinct senses, one a recommendation to do something, and another an expectation that something might happen (another way to describe your two cases.

Comment: I don't agree that the *should* of the example is a strong modal operator. *"You must be tired, but you aren't necessarily tired" is contradictory.  But "You should be tired, but you aren't necessarily tired" is not contradictory.

Comment: Is there a sub stack where all the questions are asked and answered with such high caliber? Bravo, sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

Big thanks, that's the essence:

"Must is used to express a conclusion from evidence"

and

"Should is used to express a conclusion from theory"

Comment: True only of the epistemic senses, not the deontic ones.

Comment: What do you mean by theory? Does it mean expectation ?